# Ubuntu 18.04 volume normalization

Tags: volume-control, mp3

Is there a volume normalization program I can use that is simple to install/use and can make all/most of my mp3s pay at the same volume? I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer.

Comment: I use `mp3gain` - https://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3gain/, but there's no easy installer for it (it needs to be compiled, and requires `libmpg123-dev` (which does have a package))